# How do I get the coefficient of variance for an entire month based on a groupby example?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pandas-groupby

First, I'm typing out this code.

```
covLoad = loadHr.groupby(['mo', 'OnOff', 'he']).mean()
covLoad.head()
```

which is giving me this result-

[image]

Now I want to get the mean for `period` `201606` with an `OnOff` value of `1` or `0`. How do I do that?

Comment: `loadHr.groupby(['mo', 'OnOff', 'he']).mean().reset_index().groupby(['OnOff', 'period']).mean()` does that do the trick?

Comment: That did the trick. Now how do I select the row where `OnOff` is equal to `1` and `period` is equal to `201606`? If you can provide that answer I will edit my original question and mark yours as an answer.

Comment: Got it! `agg['avg_load_hr'][1][201606]`

Comment: Yes, or `.loc[(1, 201606)]` should also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
loadHr.groupby(['mo', 'OnOff', 'he']).mean()\
.reset_index().groupby(['OnOff', 'period']).mean().loc[(1, 201606)]
```

We have to reset the index for groupby to be able to pick it up again. Since we end up with a multi-index, we have to pass a tuple to the .loc method.